# ValueError at /feed/ - invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: python, django

I need to display a feed for a user for a set of actions. I'm using Django Activity Stream for this. I just started to test the application but I can't seem to display the users feed.

As per the [Action Stream documentation](http://django-activity-stream.readthedocs.org/en/latest/streams.html#actor) I'm using the `actor_stream` function as follows

```
from actstream.models import actor_stream

def user_feed(request):
    print actor_stream(request.user)
```

This gives me a error

```
ValueError at /feed/
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '<property object at 0x2a6a520>'
```

Here is the traceback

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/jaskaran/coding/buyingiq/authentication/feed/views.py" in user_feed
  7.    print actor_stream(request.user)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __repr__
  71.         data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __iter__
  96.         self._fetch_all()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _fetch_all
  856.             self._prefetch_related_objects()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _prefetch_related_objects
  517.         prefetch_related_objects(self._result_cache, self._prefetch_related_lookups)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in prefetch_related_objects
  1598.                 obj_list, additional_prl = prefetch_one_level(obj_list, prefetcher, attr)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in prefetch_one_level
  1697.         prefetcher.get_prefetch_queryset(instances)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/generic.py" in get_prefetch_queryset
  96.             ret_val.extend(ct.get_all_objects_for_this_type(pk__in=fkeys))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py" in get_all_objects_for_this_type
  174.         return self.model_class()._base_manager.using(self._state.db).filter(**kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in filter
  590.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  608.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in add_q
  1198.         clause = self._add_q(where_part, used_aliases)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in _add_q
  1234.                     current_negated=current_negated)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in build_filter
  1125.         clause.add(constraint, AND)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/tree.py" in add
  104.         data = self._prepare_data(data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/where.py" in _prepare_data
  79.             value = obj.prepare(lookup_type, value)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/where.py" in prepare
  352.             return self.field.get_prep_lookup(lookup_type, value)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in get_prep_lookup
  371.             return [self.get_prep_value(v) for v in value]
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in get_prep_value
  613.         return int(value)

Exception Type: ValueError at /feed/
Exception Value: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '<property object at 0x2a6a520>'
```

`print type(actor_stream(request.user))` evaluates to `<class 'actstream.gfk.GFKQuerySet'>`

I even tried typcasting it as a list and then printing it but it still throws the same error. How should I be accessing the actor stream in my view?

**EDIT** - I'm using a Custom User Model if that makes any difference.

**EDIT 2** - Traceback for using Eliot's solution

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  101.                 resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  318.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  346.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  341.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  40.         __import__(name)
File "/home/jaskaran/coding/buyingiq/authentication/authentication/urls.py" in <module>
  7. admin.autodiscover()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py" in autodiscover
  29.             import_module('%s.admin' % app)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  40.         __import__(name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/allauth/account/admin.py" in <module>
  9. class EmailAddressAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/allauth/account/admin.py" in EmailAddressAdmin
  16.                                             'last_name'])))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/allauth/account/admin.py" in <lambda>
  13.                                     filter(lambda a: a and hasattr(User(), a),
File "/home/jaskaran/coding/buyingiq/authentication/users/models.py" in __init__
  86.         return self.pk
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _get_pk_val
  465.         return getattr(self, meta.pk.attname)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /feed/
Exception Value: 'UserProfile' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Comment: Did you manage to fix this problem? I'm also experiencing this

Answer (score 0):

What if you do instead :

```
from actstream.models import actor_stream

def user_feed(request):
    print actor_stream(request.user.pk) # added .pk here
```

As you can see at the end of the stacktrace (`return int(value)`), django try to convert `request.user` to an integer. I think it fails because you use a custom User model, and have not any `__int__` method defined in it. Try to had this method in your User model :

class UserModel(models.Model):

```
# your logic here

def __int__(self):
    return self.pk
```

Comment: This throws the error `AttributeError at /feed/ 'UserProfile' object has no attribute 'id'`. I've added the traceback to the original question.

Comment: Hum `Exception Value: 'UserProfile' object has no attribute 'id'` is strange. `Request.user` is a `UserProfile` instance instead of a `YourUserModel` instance. Can you provide the code from your custom usermodel please ?